# Recursive animation in Textillate

Tags: javascript

I have HTML code:

```
<h1 class="tlt" data-in-effect="rollIn">My Title</h1>
```

and JS:

```
var messages = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var position = 0;

function nextMove() {
    $('.tlt').text(messages[position]);
    position += 1;
    animate();
}

function animate() {
    $('.tlt').textillate({
        autostart: false,
        loop: false,
        in: {
            effect: 'fadeInRightBig',
            sync: true,
            delayScale: 1,
            callback: nextMove
        },
    });
}

$(function() {
    animate();
})
```

If I reload the page I can see one animation, change of text ... and that is all.  Why I don't have next animation cycle ?

**Update**

Here is a JSFiddle example [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/rX4y2/3/)

**Update 2**

This example works fine until I uncomment the line (// $('.tlt').text(messages[position]);).
Looks like I can not change this div ...

```
var messages = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var position = 0;

function animate() {
    $('.tlt').textillate({
        autostart: false,
        loop: true,
        in: {
            effect: 'fadeInRightBig',
            sync: true,
            delayScale: 1,
            callback: function () {
                if(position > 5) 
                    position = 0;

                alert(position);
                // $('.tlt').text(messages[position]);

                position += 1;
            }
        },
    });
}

$(function() {
    animate();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka, I expect nothing less than a +1 and correct answer Sir. :)

```
var messages = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var position = 0;

function nextMove() {
var tlt = $("<h1 class='tlt'>My Title</h1>");
$('div').empty();
$('div').append(tlt);
if(position < 5){
$('.tlt').text(messages[position]);
position += 1;
    animate();}
}

function animate() {
$('.tlt').textillate({
    autostart: true,
    loop: false,
    in: {
        effect: 'fadeInRightBig',
        sync: true,
        delayScale: 1,
        callback: nextMove
    },
});
}

$(function() {
animate();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ut8P3/

Comment: I have added JS Fiddle example

Comment: I just realised this is wrong, your callback never fires, and what I did is invoked function immediately.

Comment: What version of Textillate.js are you using? callbacks got introduced in v0.3.1   https://github.com/jschr/textillate

Comment: Latests from Github.  As I see, callback works fine, but only one time.

Comment: Have you tried removing textilate from element in nextMove();? It might not be running cause element is 'textilated' already

Answer (score 0):

I just want to left it here for someone who will be working on the same task.
Here is my final solution `http://jsfiddle.net/5GWLQ/1/`

```
$(function() {
    var messages = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
    var position = 0;
    var tlt_html = $("<h1 class='tlt'>My Title</h1>");

    var mainloop = function() {
        $('div').empty();   
        $('div').append(tlt_html);

        if(position >= 5) 
            position = 0;

        $('.tlt').text(messages[position]);

        var $tlt = $('.tlt').textillate({
            autostart: true,
            loop: false,
            in: {
                effect: 'fadeInRightBig',
                sync: true,
                delayScale: 2
            }
        });

        position += 1;  
        $tlt.textillate('in');
    };

    setInterval(mainloop, 1000)
})
```